# conditional filter in query mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have 3 user roles stored in my users' collection [supervisors, markets, clients].

The market wants to perform a search query to find the users,

I want the market to be able to list all the users except for the markets,

I want him to be able to see only himself, and to exclude the other markets.

---

In real life,

The data looks as follows:

```json
[
  {
    "role": "supervisor",
    "name": "S1",
    "branch": "School #A",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "role": "market",
    "name": "M1",
    "branch": "School #A",
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "role": "market",
    "name": "M2",
    "branch": "School #A",
    "id": 3
  },
  {
    "role": "client",
    "name": "C1",
    "branch": "School #A",
    "id": 4
  },
  {
    "role": "client",
    "name": "C2",
    "branch": "School #A",
    "id": 5
  }
]
```

I want to perform a query which should return this output:

```json
[
  {
    "role": "supervisor",
    "name": "S1",
    "branch": "School #A",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "role": "market",
    "name": "M1",
    "branch": "School #A",
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "role": "client",
    "name": "C1",
    "branch": "School #A",
    "id": 4
  },
  {
    "role": "client",
    "name": "C2",
    "branch": "School #A",
    "id": 5
  }
]
```

The query should exclude this document:

```json
  {
    "role": "market",
    "name": "M2",
    "branch": "School #A",
    "id": 3
  }
```

How to perform this query.

I am using **mongosh**.

```bash
# this is how the command looks like at the moment:
$ db.users.find({  })
```

Please note:

I can't do it like this:

```bash
# this is how the command looks like at the moment:
$ db.users.find({ id: { $ne: 3 } })
```

Because more users (markets) will register everyday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$or` for this:

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {role: {$ne: "market"}},
    {id: 2}
  ]
})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_PT8VklKdqh)